# Running a single app on rdesktop to a Windows XP/Vista machine from Linux

Tags: linux, windows, remote-access

I need to connect to a windows XP/Vista machine using rdesktop from Linux and execute a script on the windows machine. Of course, I will authenticate to the machine from the command line on linux. The -s option in rdesktop is supposed to be able to do this, but it just opens up a normal rdesktop desktop to me. Iam using rdesktop 1.5.0 from Ubuntu. To clarify, I would like to NOT see the remote desktop at all. I just want the command/script executed on Windows. If I need to do this on a remote linux machine, I could have just said

```
ssh user@host command
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Winexe](http://eol.ovh.org/winexe/) will also allow you to execute a single command/script remotely from a Linux box.  Since you are running Ubuntu, you can install it easily by executing:

apt-get install wmi-client

Comment: Additionally, since you mentioned that you're executing it remotely, this approach would require an established VPN connection.